# How to save fields and upload a file to firebase with one submit button in Vue JS 3 and Axios

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, axios, vuejs3, firebase-storage

I have a form where I am adding players to a database. Without the image upload, the form works, but when I try to upload an image to Firebase storage, it is now working.
I am adding all the code to the Add Player Page.

So, the only thing here that is not happening is saving the image URL to the Firebase Real-Time database.

The player data is added to the db. The collection is called players.
I have a Firebase Storage folder called photos.

I need to have the URL of the photo uploaded to be saved to the player record on the db.

My component starts here

```html
<template>
   <div class="container my-4">
        <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
            <div class="card-body pt-2">
                <h2><i class="fas fa-pen"></i>Add Player</h2>
    <form class="row g-3" @submit.prevent="onAddPlayer">
      <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="player.fullname" required>
          </div>
<div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Position</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="player.position" required>
          </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
      
      <label>Photo:</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" @change="handleFileUpload" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<script>

import axios from 'axios';
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
import { getDatabase, ref as dbRef, push } from "firebase/database";
import Datepicker from 'vuejs3-datepicker';
export default {
  name: 'FormSubmit',
  components: {
        Datepicker
    },
  data() {
        return {
          player: {
                fullname: '',
                position: '',
                photoUrl: ''}            
        }
    },
  methods: {

    onAddPlayer() {
            axios.post(`https://teamsheet-23-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/players.json`, 
            this.player).then((response) => {
              console.log('response')
            })
        },
    async submitForm() {
      // Push data to Firebase Realtime Database
      const db = getDatabase();
      const newPlayerRef = push(dbRef(db, 'players'));
      await set(newPlayerRef, {
        fullname: this.fullname,
        position: this.position,
        photo: this.photoUrl
      });

      // Upload file to Firebase Storage
      const storage = getStorage();
      const fileRef = ref(storage, `photos/${newPlayerRef.key}`);
      await uploadBytes(fileRef, this.selectedFile);

      // Reset form
      this.fullname = '';
      this.position = '';
      this.photoUrl = '';
      this.$refs.fileInput.value = '';
    },
    handleFileUpload(event) {
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
      this.uploadFile();
    },
    async uploadFile() {
      const storage = getStorage();
      const fileRef = ref(storage, `photos/${this.selectedFile.name}`);
      await uploadBytes(fileRef, this.selectedFile);
      this.photoUrl = await fileRef.getDownloadURL();
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .calendar {
    color: #666;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Why are you using Axios / the Firebase REST API when you could just use the relevant SDK (Realtime Database / Cloud Firestore)?

Comment: I was following a tutorial and used that option. I am starting to learn, but I am building a little personal project as I am doing that. At the moment, I just wish to have this add work. I will then check the API option. Thanks for the prompt response, but do you have a solution to the issue I listed?

Comment: There are three asynchronous operations happening here, to two completely separate Firebase products: 1) uploading data to Cloud Storage, 2) getting the download URL for that data, and 3) then writing that URL to the Realtime Database. The first debugging step should be to figure out which of these steps is failing. For example: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I'd find a better tutorial or just use the [official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start)