# The URL of the image uploaded to Firebase is not being saved to the Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I have an app built in VueJS3, using Firebase Real-Time Database, and Firebase Storage. There is an Add Form adding a record to the database, and uploading a file to the storage. My code is adding a record successfully and uploading the file successfully, but it is not saving the file URL to the database photoUrl field.

Here is the code for the markup and the script.

```html
<template>
  <div class="container my-4">
       <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
           <div class="card-body pt-2">
               <h2><i class="fas fa-pen"></i>Add Player</h2>
   <form class="row g-3" @submit.prevent="onAddPlayer">
     <div class="col-md-6">
           <label>Full Name</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="player.fullname" required>
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-6">
           <label>Position</label>
           <select class="form-control" v-model="player.position" required>
             <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
             <option>Goal Keeper</option>
             <option>Defender</option>
             <option>Midfielder</option>
             <option>Forward</option>
             <option>Coach</option>
             <option>Assistant Coach</option>
           </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
           <label>Jersey Number</label>
           <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="player.number" required>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
           <label>Class Of</label>
            <div id="calendar" class="calendar">
              <datepicker placeholder="Select Year" :minimum-view="'year'" :maximum-view="'year'"
                @changedYear="handleChangedYear" :value="player.class" :typeable="true" name="datepicker"
                id="input-id" class="class-of-calendar" input-class="" v-model="player.classof" required>
              </datepicker>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
           <label>Email</label>
           <input type="email" class="form-control" v-model="player.email" required>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
           <label>Phone</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="player.phone" required>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
           <label>GPA</label>
           <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" v-model="player.gpa" required>
         </div>

     <div class="col-md-6">
     
     <label>Photo:</label>
     <input type="file" class="form-control" @change="handleFileUpload" required>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12">
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </div>
   </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

and here is the script

```html
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
import { getDatabase, ref as dbRef, push } from "firebase/database";
import Datepicker from 'vuejs3-datepicker';
export default {
  name: 'FormSubmit',
  components: {
    Datepicker
  },
  data() {
    return {
      player: {
        fullname: '',
        position: '',
        number: '',
        class: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        gpa: '',
        photoUrl: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {

    onAddPlayer() {
      axios.post(`myfirebase-url.com/players.json`,
        this.player).then((response) => {
          console.log('response')
        })
    },
    async submitForm() {
      // Push data to Firebase Realtime Database
      const db = getDatabase();
      const newPlayerRef = push(dbRef(db, 'players'));
      await set(newPlayerRef, {
        fullname: this.fullname,
        position: this.position,
        number: this.number,
        class: this.class,
        email: this.email,
        phone: this.phone,
        gpa: this.gpa,
        photo: this.photoUrl
      });

      // Upload file to Firebase Storage
      const storage = getStorage();
      const fileRef = ref(storage, `photos/${newPlayerRef.key}`);
      await uploadBytes(fileRef, this.selectedFile);

      // Reset form
      this.fullname = '';
      this.position = '';
      this.number = '';
      this.class = '';
      this.email = '';
      this.phone = '';
      this.gpa = '';
      this.photoUrl = '';
      this.$refs.fileInput.value = '';
    },
    handleFileUpload(event) {
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
      this.uploadFile();
    },
    async uploadFile() {
      const storage = getStorage();
      const fileRef = ref(storage, `photos/${this.selectedFile.name}`);
      await uploadBytes(fileRef, this.selectedFile);
      this.photoUrl = await fileRef.getDownloadURL();
    },

    saveToDatabase() {
      const databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('players')
      axios.post(databaseRef, {
        url: this.selectedFile
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
    whatImage() {
      uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function (downloadURL) {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What have you done to debug this so far?  Could you explain what's happening that's different than what you expect?  Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I expected that the downloadUrl() response would be captured once the file is uploaded and that response it supposed to return to url of the image. I expected that the full url would be saved to the photoUrl field in the database. Currently, that field is coming empty. All the other fields are being saved and the upload is properly working. I tried debugging, using dev tool, but I am getting nothing.

Comment: Again, why are you persisting with the Realtime Database REST API? Is this _any_ different to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76168618/283366)?

Comment: You don't seem to call `saveToDatabase` anywhere in the code you shared.

Comment: The code here is confusing because you have **two** different calls to getDonwloadURL, and apparently *three* different places where you add data to the database.  It's not really clear what you're expecting here or how to reproduce this problem.  Please firm up your code and debugging, and **edit the question** to provide more details (don't leave details in comments).

Comment: @Phil my previous code was not uploading the photo to the database. And even after posting a different request, no one responded. This is after fixing it, now the only item left is to save the Url to the Firebase Realtime database.